# POCO Controllers in MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, poco, asp.net-core-mvc

The [ASP.NET vNext Overview](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/overview) says you can create POCO controllers by injecting `IActionResultHelper`:

```
public class HomeController
{
    // Helpers can be dependency injected into the controller
    public HomeController(IActionResultHelper resultHelper)
    {
        Result = resultHelper;
    }

    private IActionResultHelper Result { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Result.Json(new { message = "Poco controllers!" });
    }
}
```

I'm trying to implement this, however, I cannot find this interface. It appears that is [no longer](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/IActionResultHelper.cs) in [the source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core).

What is the current correct approach for creating POCO controllers?

Comment: This answer from the asp.net forum clarifies the situation http://forums.asp.net/t/1997389.aspx?IActionResultHelper+missing+in+CTP2+

Comment: @WiktorZychla - yeah, that doesn't clarify much.. just that IActionResultHelper is gone and you create results like you always could.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: this clarify everything. The source code comment says `The property ActionContext gets injected by InitializeController from DefaultControllerFactory.`. The example shows then that the `ActionContext` gives you access to the `HttpContext` and other infrastructure stuff you would normally get by inheriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the CTP release of Visual Studio 14 on 2014-10-06, the way to inject services is:

```
public class HomeController
{
    // Use the ActivateAttribute to inject services into your controller
    [Activate]
    public ViewDataDictionary ViewData { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return new ViewResult() { ViewData = ViewData };
    }
}
```

Source: [Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC 6 - Mike Wasson, asp.net](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/overview)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this code was removed about a month ago, and it looks like they are going with a different attribute based method of creating POCO controllers.  There is no IActionResultHelper, you just create new ActionResult instances...

If you look through these issues, you get a feel for what's happening.

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/316
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/597
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/617

There seems to be a new [Activate] attribute used in POCO controllers.  See this sample.

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/samples/MvcSample.Web/Home2Controller.cs

There's also this sample

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/samples/MvcSample.Web/SimplePocoController.cs

Apparently, the new DefaultControllerFactory requires that POCO's still use the Controller suffix in the naming of the controller, but you can name a controller anything if it derives from the Controller class.